# Github - see all emojis reactions in detail

Tags: github, emoji

I have a question about github.

I have a comment in a PR, which has some reactions for other users, in the form of emojis likes hearts, thumbs up, etc.

Well ... how can I see all users that reacted to my comment?

so far what I get is ....

[image]

How can I get the full list of users that reacted?

Answer (score 3):

The following cURL command will get all reactions on the first post of an issue or PR ID `${NUMBER}` for the repository `${ORG}/${REPO}`:

```
curl -L -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${API_KEY}" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" https://api.github.com/repos/${ORG}/${REPO}/issues/${NUMBER}/reactions -o "output.txt"
```

Note that for private repositories, you'll need a GitHub API key as `${API_KEY}`; for public repositories, you can remove the `Authorization: Bearer ${API_KEY}` header as authorization is not required there.

If you're just interested in the list of users who reacted, you can pipe it through `jq` like so:

```
curl -L -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${API_KEY}" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" https://api.github.com/repos/${ORG}/${REPO}/issues/${NUMBER}/reactions | jq '.[].user.login'
```

Or to see both the user and what they reacted with:

```
curl -L -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${API_KEY}" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" https://api.github.com/repos/${ORG}/${REPO}/issues/${NUMBER}/reactions | jq '.[] | "\(.user.login) \(.content)"'
```

The API documentation is available at https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reactions?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-reactions-for-an-issue

Also note that both PRs and issues use the same numbering scheme; this API endpoint will not differentiate between those two types.

Answer (score 2):

It's not yet supported by the GitHub GUI directly, but people have requested the feature for a long time.
But after looking at the answers of [@janez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22097371/janez-ivan) and [@joshua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5253131/joshua-boniface), I looked up a bit and found you can use **curl commands** anywhere, like in **cmd** or **google colab**, or you can use **github CLI** or **javascript get requests** to get a JSON output that may give you an actual list. I was unable to find a comment with a huge amount of likes to actually test if it gives the real list in case of more likes, but I guess it will work. 
How to use it can be found in this link [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reactions/reactions?apiVersion=2022-11-28#about-reactions), which is an actual documentation page from github docs. 
I tested the codes given for listing the reactions for a **PR comment** but found that if the PRs are closed, then they are not even listed. Maybe we can check the reactions on open PRs only for now, or maybe I didn't get the documentation clearly. You can always give it a good read . 
I checked to list the reactions for an issue listed in someone else's **repository**, named discussion, and it worked. Here's what it looked like:

```
!curl -L \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
-H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
https://api.github.com/repos/v2ray/discussion/issues/910/reactions
```

And it gave me a **JSON output** with my name, so I guess it should give a long list as well, with good enough likes. 
The output I got looked like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 189032473,
    "node_id": "REA_lAHOCIo_V8525oQRzgtEaBk",
    "user": {
      "login": "PreyumKr",
      "id": 77330179,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjc3MzMwMTc5",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/77330179?u=da962981911e3392334f9450564b1849bb4a3422&v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/PreyumKr",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/PreyumKr",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/PreyumKr/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/PreyumKr/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/PreyumKr/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/PreyumKr/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/PreyumKr/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/PreyumKr/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/PreyumKr/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/PreyumKr/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/PreyumKr/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "content": "+1",
    "created_at": "2023-11-28T13:20:53Z"
  }
]
```

I also noticed that when I wanted to find the list for the reactions of the discussion forum of the github community channel, it was not possible to get the results as it needed access permissions, which my generated **personal access token** was unable to get. I basically did a curl to obtain the community page's team slug, which is needed for the requests to see their discussion reactions, but it was restricted. So, I guess the CLI approach is only till what is under our reach and other public repositories.

So, there are command-line approaches available for now and that too for active PRs and only public repositories (or wherever your personal access token has access, in the case of the community page) to get the reactions' list, as per my research.

Hope a GUI-based option will come soon with better options and more reach than now .

Comment: o man, what a pity.

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have updated the answer, which may be more helpful to you now than my previous answer. Hope it helps you get the list of people you wanted.